# Application variable from Global.asax returning null value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I 've created a very small application which prints the number of active sessions on webpage.
The global.asax.cs code is given as below

```
namespace WebApp
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["TotalOnline"] = 0;
    }
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["TotalOnline"] = (int)Application["TotalOnline"] + 1;
    }
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Application["TotalOnline"] = (int)Application["TotalOnline"] - 1;
    }
}
}
```

the hell.aspx.cs code is given as below

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public partial class hell : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = (int)Application["TotalOnline"];
            Response.Write("The no of users online are "+ a );
        }
    }
}
```

the hell.aspx source is as below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="hell.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.hell" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I m trying run in firefox giving an NullReference Exception for

```
 int a = (int)Application["TotalOnline"];
```

I don't understand why.....Please help me...thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code where you're setting `Application["TotalOnline"] = null`?

Comment: No dude.....no where i initialized to null

Comment: Add breakpoints in the global.asax. Make sure the Application_Start and such are executing and that it is being set to an int.

Comment: Your code works, it has to be something else - maybe your server. Handle the Application_End event and do some logging to see if something is causing the App Pool to shutdown or recycle, for instance.

Comment: @Crowcoder even if the app pool recycles, the Application_Start should trigger causing it to be 0, not null. I suspect his global.asax is not being run.